# Does the ankle rule apply to modern day clothing

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

Does the ankle rule apply to modern day clothing?

What about wearing pants/trousers that cover the ankle, or is it just the trailing the lower garment with pride is haram?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE!Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what you are talking about. So that others may find this post helpful. What does this "rule" say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Keeping the lower garment above the Ankle is applicable even today.

> Prophet said "Whatever of the izaar (lower garment) is below the ankles is in the Fire." (al-Bukhaari, no. 5787)

More reports from prophet clearly indicate that the action is to be followed without any opinion or choice even in today's world.

> "The Messenger of Allaah took hold of the muscle of my calf (or his calf) and said, ‘This is where the izaar should stop; if you insist, it may be lower, but it should not reach the ankles.’" (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, who said this is a saheeh hasan hadeeth; see Sunan al-Tirmidhi, no. 1783)

Other hadith which speaks of Abu Bakr failing to keep his lower garmnet above the ankles is because his garment kept slipping. Abu Bakr kept his garment above the ankles.

> Abu Bakr said to him, "O Messenger of Allaah, my izaar slips down if I do not pay attention to it." He said: "You are not one of those who do it out of pride." (Reported by al-Bukhaari, no. 5784)

Comment: "Prophet said above to Abu Bakr only, not to entire ummah." - Did the prophet mention this?

Comment: Have deleted that comment, may Allah return your goodness

Comment: https://sunnah.com/search/?q=izar+pride